# PHP & MySQL - Popular Links Based on Clicks and Time

Tags: php, mysql, relevance

At the moment I am sorting popular links by total clicks. But I also have timestamps for each visit. How can I sort links not only by total clicks but also using time, so only the most relevant are showed at the top?

```
table link_clicks
-----------------
link_id
link_time
```

Comment: do you not have a link_hits column? or do you add a new record for every hit

Comment: I add a new record for every hit and I have all hits count stored in another table.

Comment: no prob was just asking so as to give an answer but Michael beat me too it

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` `link_id` and just use a date constraint in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT link_id, COUNT(*) AS num_clicks
FROM link_clicks
WHERE link_time >= '2011-05-20'
GROUP BY link_id
ORDER BY num_clicks DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY total_clicks, link_time DESC;
```